# Reading specific .dat file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, csv

I need some help reading a .dat file in MATLAB (as an array).

The content of the file (if I open it with notepad) is like this

```
"TOA5","CR800Series","CR800","36460","CR800.Std.28","CPU:HAC.CR8","48946","HAC_Meteo_Data_05"
"TIMESTAMP","RECORD","Anonymous1","Anonymous2","Tair_Avg","Tair_Std","RH_Avg","RH_Std","SolRad_Avg","SolRad_Std","AcVirTemp_Avg","AcVirTemp_Std","WV_XYZ_Avg","WV_XYZ_Std","WD_Elev_Avg","WD_Elev_Std","WD_Azim_Avg","WD_Azim_Std","WV_Azim_Avg","WV_Azim_Std","WV_X_Avg","WV_X_Std","WV_Y_Avg","WV_Y_Std","WV_Z_Avg","WV_Z_Std","PTemp","batt_volt_Min"
"TS","RN","","","deg_Celsiou","deg_Celsiou","%","%","W/m2","W/m2","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","","Smp","Smp","Avg","Std","Avg","Std","Avg","Std","Avg","Std","Avg","Std","Avg","Std","Avg","Std","Avg","Std","Avg","Std","Avg","Std","Avg","Std","Smp","Min"
"2016-05-21 04:05:00",9825,105,711,3.93,0.014,100,0,"NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN",23.01,13.87
"2016-05-21 04:10:00",9826,105,711,3.934,0.018,100,0,"NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN",23.01,13.87
```

There are many more lines underneath and I don't really need the first few ones. All I need is to have the numbers
in their cells. When I use Excel or Libre Office to open the file, it opens without the commas or the quotes etc.

What would be the best way to read the file? I found some way, but I am missing something to make it work properly :

```
f= fopen('x.dat');
data=fread(f);
fclose(f);`

y = importdata('x.csv') %I converted my .dat to a .csv and that worked well, but I really need it to read from the .dat file

fIDF=fopen(nameFile);
NephtDataAr0= textscan(fIDF, '%s %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %s %s','Delimiter',',','CommentStyle','[');
fclose(fIDF); 
%Someone that has written a program to read some similar data from a .txt file, used the line above. Could that be of any use?

filename = 'csvlist.dat';
M = csvread(filename)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error using dlmread (line 147)
Mismatch between file and format string.
Trouble reading 'Numeric' field from file (row number 1, field number 1) ==>
"TOA5","CR800Series","CR800","36460","CR800.Std.28","CPU:HAC.CR8","48946","HAC_Meteo_Data_05"\n

Error in csvread (line 48)
    m=dlmread(filename, ',', r, c);

Error in readfile2 (line 2)
M = csvread(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `Readtable`, check it out:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/import-mixed-text-and-numeric-data-from-a-text-file.html